# UIScrollView freezes after using SetContentOffset or scrollRectToVisible

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with paging enabled and I want to be able to jump to pages further down the line rather then swiping through each one. I attempted to use both setContentOffset and scrollRectToVisible. They both scroll the view to the correct point but after scrolling animated or not the scrollview becomes frozen and unresponsive to any touches. I tried setting it to the first responder but it changed nothing. I have a button outside of the scroll view and it still functions fine after the setContentOffset. There are also buttons inside the scrollview and not only will the scrollview not respond to touch for dragging but the buttons will not recognize the touches either.

```
        [mainScroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(mainScroll.frame.size.width*4, 0.0) animated:YES];
```

tldr; I can scroll through the view fine, through all the pages but when I try and call a setContentOffset or a scrollRectToVisible I get 'frozen' after the move.

Comment: There is no log/output. The application does not crash. When calling setContentOffset it seems to just turn the UIScrollView into something that can only be controlled by setContentOffset's from that point further. It can respond to setContentOffset but it will not respond to touch on the UIScrollView, for dragging or for interaction with items within it. Interesting note: after calling setContentOffset if I call [scrollView flashScrollIndicators]; nothing is shown.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, stupid mistake.

In my scrollViewDidScroll I had:

```
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
```

and in my scrollViewDidEndDecelerating

```
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

and in scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate

```
if(!decelerate){scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;}
```

I had this to prevent button presses and any random things during a page transition. But when setContentOffset is called it only causes scrollViewDidScroll to be called and neither of the other two, so the UserInteraction was never set back to Enabled, but only when using setContentOffset.

Simple fix.

Comment: add also http://stackoverflow.com/a/15160174/1067147 after change size of content