# setContentOffset on UIScrollView the right way

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I'm using this code to scroll my `UIScrollView` down because I'm adding a new `UIView` on it from the bottom and I want to scroll down to it. I do it like this:

```
CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(mainScrollView.contentOffset.x, mainScrollView.contentOffset.y + floorf(bottomAttachmentView.frame.size.height / bottomAttachmentView.multFactor));
[mainScrollView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];
```

I basically add my new element's height to the `y` of `UIScrollView`'s `contentOffset` but sometimes it scrolls out of the scrollView `contentSize`, lower, that it is possible to scroll. It happens because I modify the `contentSize` before calling the method above and the height of the Scroll View shrinks.

How do you call the `setContentOffset` so it wouldn't make my scrollView scroll out of it's own `contentSize`? Thanks!

Comment: You shrink the mainScrollView, then add bottomAttachmentView to the mainScrollView, and want to scroll to it?

Comment: @Rikkles yes, but the thing is it only takes some bottom 30% of the `scrollView` and when I try to use this function it simply scrolls out of the `scrollView`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All I had to do actually, was scroll my `UIScrollView` to the bottom like this:

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, [mainScrollView contentSize].height - mainScrollView.frame.size.height);
[mainScrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

Comment: This solution would be a bit cleaner, if you would take an bottom content inset into account also:
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, (self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.frame.size.height + self.scrollView.contentInset.bottom));

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this to scroll to bottom of scrollView (Swift 4)

```
let targetRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: mainScrollView.contentSize.height, width: 1, height: 1)
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(targetRect, animated: true)
```